# 'exception has been thrown by a target of invocation' when starting up Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I start up Visual Studio 2010 I often get the error `'exception has been thrown by a target of invocation'` which prevents me from opening Visual Studio. A reboot of my computer makes the error go away, but a few days later it returns.

What causes this error and how can I get rid of it?

I've found a lot of questions on SO that mention this error when running their code in Visual Studio, but none when opening Visual Studio.

Comment: This was causing all kinds of issues for me, not just for Visual Studio. I was losing shortcut icons that used %windir% and my SSMS wouldn't open.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It seems the problem was that my system path became too long for Windows to handle: it was [over the 2048 characters limit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/03/9957320.aspx) (hat tip to [this article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/501190/receiving-...Title)).

Comment: I cannot tell you how much time this just saved me.

Comment: can somebody tell me, what part to remove from **PATH** variable, to shorten it down? I don't have any idea, which path to remove will cause any problem or something.

Comment: @Zeeshan: the contents of your PATH depend on the programs you have installed. So first try to remove any mentions of programs you no longer use. The default PATH for Windows 7 is `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;`, so it is probably not a good idea to remove any of these.

Comment: @BioGeek Thank you. I can paths also set for my WLAN card, Graphic card etc. Since these type of programs are always in use, so these type of paths shouldn't be removed, rite?

Comment: Hmm -SQL Server 2014 pushed it over the edge.

Comment: @GerryColl Same here! And for future visitors to this page, I recommend using regedit to make the change rather than trusting what you see in SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe.

Comment: @influent why do you not trust SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe to set the path?  And what is the registry key for the path?

Comment: Why is this so heavily upvoted when the main solution to the answer is behind a sign in wall and not c/p into here?

Comment: @BioGeek how do you find out such unrelated things ?

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2012 today. Something seemed to be gone wrong during the first setup, so it helped to **delete** these registry entries:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config
```

Visual Studio will then setup again when you start it. You can also just **rename** it.

Comment: This fixed my problem after restarting the computer

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Studio, solution was to **reduce the SYSTEM PATH variable length**.

Symptoms: After one instance of Visual Studio 2012 was started, any other attempt to start another or one of SQL Server Management Studio would fail. The computer reboot would allow me to start again a single instance of VS2012. 
Repairing the VS2012 installation didn't help.

Comment: Once again, having forgotten this symptom, this question and answer saved me an immense amount of time.  Trimming my path resolved the same problem with SQL Server Management Studio after installing Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 4):

None of these solutions solved the problem with my Visual Studio 2012, but I finally managed to fix it by installing the latest Update 4 from the [Visual Studio website](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Answer (score 3):

My path also seemed to affect accessing Advanced System Settings from Control Panel\system\Advanced system Settings so I was unable to edit the path.

Had to launch this from windows\system32 to display the Advanced System Settings dialog, then edit te environment variables from there.

A recent install of the MEAN stack had added a path statement for my user account. I removed this setting entirely and then VS2010 and the Advanced System Settings dialog started without problem.

Comment: What did you launch in system32?

Answer (score 3):

[BioGeek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12750664/2055187) answer fixed my issue. In my case, the overflow of system path not only break visual studio, it also break the GUI to change system path itself.

I got error on: Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings.

The workaround is run c:\windows\system32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem while trying to run the "**Task Runner Explorer**" in **VS2015**, I got an error:
"**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocatio**n".

I solved it by reinstalling only the "**Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools**" patch (DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe) from [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935?SRC=VSIDE) link.

Answer (score 2):

I received this error when I installed SQL Server Express 2014 on a machine that already had 2012.  I installed it with tools, which apparently broke SSMS 2012.  Specifically when trying to "Edit top 200 rows" the error was thrown.

Using SSMS 2014 seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

To add to BioGeek's answer. You don't necessarily have to get rid of entries in your path, you can work around the character limitation by introducing more variables.

e.g.

```
PATH = {1800 CHARACTER LONG STRING}{500 MORE CHARACTERS}
```

You would add a EXTENDEDPATH variable, like so:

```
EXTENDEDPATH = {500 MORE CHARACTERS}
```

And finally you reference this variable in your PATH

```
PATH = {2000 CHARACTER LONG STRING};%EXTENDEDPATH%;
```

I'd recommend leaving at least 100-200 characters of breathing room in your path so you don't have to be babysitting the PATH environment variable every time you install something.

Answer (score 0):

System Path variable is too long. Copy current content to notepad and remove repeated entries and unwanted enteries and copy back to path variable.

Comment: This answer already exists [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12750664/1730674).

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was due to an invalid key in the web.config file. Try to revert last changes made to the file.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem but i figured out "connectionStrings" must be under "configSections" in the web.config

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs due to long path in your environment variable windows supports only 2048 characters.
In order to solve this problem you need to remove few environment varibale from your system from PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Atmel Studio 7. Resolved by deleting the *.componentinfo.xml file in the same folder as the project file.